# Value of type AppDelegate has no member 'windows'?

Tags: swift, appdelegate, swift5

I'm trying to change the tintColor in the AppDelegate file with the `self.window.tintColor` but XCode gives me an error saying that AppDelegate doesn't have a member Window. I searched everywhere how to change the global tintcolor and in every stackoverflow post people say we can do it using that code in the AppDelegate file. Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post code as text not image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's xcode 11 add it inside `willConnectTo` of `SceneDelegate`

```
guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
self.window?.tintColor = .red
```